# Edit a phone list pattern using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have just started reading about regex today and I have a question if what i am trying to do below is possible?

I have a file containing phone numbers some are in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format but some are in xxx-xxxx format.

so eg telephonelist:

```
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
934-2368
731-7056
251-5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

so the objective is to add (000) in all of the lines that is not in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.

What i have worked out so far is basically to grep the output and write them into a new file matching a regex pattern, and do another grep output but this time not matching the regex and append it to the same file; as below.

```
grep "([0-9]\{3\}) [0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}" testfile > newtestfile ; grep -v "([0-9]\{3\}) [0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}" testfile | sed 's/^/(000) /' >> newtestfile
```

But this will actually change the order of the list, as the new file becomes

```
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
(000) 934-2368
(000) 731-7056
(000) 251-5372
```

Is there any way to do this without changing the order?
I have been researching using sed, awk and nl, but nothing so far.
I am a noob..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `grep` and do it all in `sed`, conditionally

```
sed '/^([0-9][0-9][0-9])/! s/^/(000) /' testfile > newtestfile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed 's/^[^(]/(000) &/' file
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(000) 934-2368
(000) 731-7056
(000) 251-5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

Answer (score 2):

Really simple with awk:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{$1="(000) " $1}1' file
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(000) 934-2368
(000) 731-7056
(000) 251-5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

Comment: Hi, this works thanks.... Never thought it would be that simple. so if am not wrong the logic goes like ... If awk find any record with Number of Fields equal to 1 then add "(000) " followed by the original first field into the first field..  but what is number "1" after the closing curly bracket "}" is for? if i remove that, the command returns no value..... Thanks

Comment: @HutanRimba  The `1` is equivalent to `{print $0}` (which is equivalent to `{print}`). It tells awk to print every line found.

Answer (score 2):

Some variation using awk

```
awk '!/\(/ {$0="(000) "$0} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '@n = /\d+/g; unshift @n, "000" if @n==2; printf "(%s) %s-%s\n", @n'
```